# No suitable method found for (no arguments)

Tags: java

I have tried to figure this out for a while now, but nothing has worked..
I assume this is pretty basic knowledge, but how do I call the methods inside the main method?
I get the error message in the title

+

method Utskrift.utskrift1(String) is not applicable
   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
   method Utskrift.utskrift1(double,double) is not applicable
   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

And heres the code

```
class Utskrift
{

public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    utskrift();
  }
  public static void utskrift(String tekst)
  {
    System.out.println("tekst");
  }
  public static void utskrift1(double tall1, double tall2)
  {
    System.out.println(tall1 + tall2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your method takes a String as an argument. You are not passing it while calling it from `main()`

Comment: in your `main` method, just change `utskrift();` to `utskrift(null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `utskrift` method takes 1 argument, however you pass none.

Instead use:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    utskrift("tekst");
  }
  public static void utskrift(String tekst)
  {
    System.out.println(tekst);
  }
  public static void utskrift1(double tall1, double tall2)
  {
    System.out.println(tall1 + tall2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!! That worked, and now I figured out how to call "utskrift1" too:)

Comment: You can call utskift1 with uskift1(3,5) to add 3 and 5